# Convert vector of uint8 to string

Tags: c++, string, stdvector, stdstring, uint8t

I have a pointer to a vector of type uint8.

How would I take this pointer and convert the data in the vector into a full string representative of its content?

Comment: You should already know the length from the vector->size().  Does it have non-ascii data within it or not?

Comment: It is all ascii data.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could just initialize the `std::string` with the sequence obtained from the `std::vector<uint8_t>`:

```
std::string str(v->begin(), v->end());
```

There is no need to play any tricks checking whether the `std::vector<uint8_t>` is empty: if it is, the range will be empty. However, you might want to check if the pointer is `v` is null. The above requires that it points to a valid object.

Comment: Is it okay if I ask why you were gone for so long?

Comment: @0x499602D2: You mean, why I didn't answer questions for a while? It's simple: I was busy trying to get work done besides work. Right now I'm to busy at work to work besides work.

Comment: I'm surprised this answer is accepted because it does not produce something "representative of its content". If you vector is "{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}" then your output will be a string of non-displayable characters!

Comment: @JérémyPouyet: it seems we interpreted the question differently: I read as asking to convert a sequence of bytes in a `std::vector<uint8_t>` to the same sequence of bytes in a `std::string`. The answer matches that interpretation. You interpretation seems to be _formatting_ the content of a `std::vector<...>` and storing the result in a `std::string`. That question is often asked/answered although possibly in two parts: How to format a vector? How to direct the output of a stream to a string?

Answer (score 10):

For those who wants the conversion be done *after* a string is declared, you may use std::string::assign(), e.g.:

```
std::string str;
std::vector<uint8_t> v;
str.assign(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: Great! I guess `str = std::string(.., ..)` also works. But this is maybe faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<uint8_t> *p;
string str(
    p && !p->empty() ? &*p->begin()             : NULL,
    p && !p->empty() ? &*p->begin() + p->size() : NULL);
```

Comment: There is no need to play any tricks with `empty()` vectors: they'll return a valid range and `std::string` has a constructor taking a pair of input iterators.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Oh yeah you're right, I have a habit of doing this because I sometimes compile with an old STL implementation that doesn't have that templated overload, totally forgot.

Comment: yes, the old RogueWave implementation still shipping as the default standard C++ library for Sun Studio, I guess. If I had to use that I would actually use `std::copy(v->begin(), v->end(), std::back_inserter(str));`.